# IDE for Chromebooks without Developer Mode Acess

Tags: python, google-chrome-os

I am starting a computer club at my school, and I am running into a problem with Chromebooks.
The new freshmen are given Toshiba Chromebooks, where developer mode access to blocked.

We are going to start using Python. I would like for the people with Chromebooks to edit and run their programs from their computer. I have looked into Nitrous.Io, but I do not like this option, since they would eventually have to pay to make more programs and I don't think you can even run it.

**Is there any way for the members with Chromebooks to be able to code and run their programs without breaking into Developer Mode?**

I have briefly talked to the tech guy at my school about this, but he doesn't understand much about Chromebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Chromebook to check it on, but there are quite a few IDEs for it
that advertise support for Python and have free subscription plans that might be
sufficient for your needs, but requiring Internet connection to their servers.

Here is the list that I managed to find (in no special order) :

[Python Fiddle](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python-fiddle/imldfcloildiapnfjoocfpdmoajnjelf)
[PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)
[codebox](https://www.codebox.io/?affiliate=533d9a60475541020000068f)
[Koding](https://koding.com/)
[Codio](https://codio.com/)
[Cloud9](https://c9.io/)
[Runnable](http://runnable.com/)
[SourceLair](https://www.sourcelair.com)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this thread has had a post,
but I thought I'd put in my two cents
in case anyone else is wondering like I was a couple months ago. 
I had the exact same problem, just I only had a Chromebook to use
as a solo developer, and didn't want to run Linux. 
Assuming that you are just coding HTML, JavaScript, and CSS,
as far as offline, fast, quality editors that I have found,
I have stuck with two main ones: [VSC for the Web](https://vscode.dev/) and [DevTools Workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/workspaces/). 
Both allow for local editing and saving the code of any files you need. DevTools knocks JavaScript ([Debugger!](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/)), CSS, and HTML editing out of the park, but VSC allows for so much more user customization with separate windows for different code files, extensions, and keyboard shortcuts, even though it has less access to the files (cough cough *NO CONSOLE*) than DevTools. They both work great online too, and you can use DevTools with shared Google Drive files for cloud saving/sharing and VSC with extensions for collaboration online editing. However, if you have constant access to the internet, [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) is a great resource for coding too, as well as [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/?html,output).

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Chromebooks aren't designed for programming, and even with developer mode enabled they're limited.

If your school has a BYOD (Bring Your Own Device) solution, I'll suggest that you get students to bring their own laptop computer in for the computer club, or alternatively try and secure a grant from the school's finance department in order to purchase the laptop computers that you need.
With this method you could also try and get access to *Microsoft Dreamspark* through the school, which I advise as students can get professional-grade software for free (such as Visual Studio 2013 Pro). It's also possible to get non-server operating systems from there too, but it requires an Educational Institution Premium subscription which would cost the school around $300/month, so perhaps this should only be considered if you're serious about the computer club (and that you have other areas of the school that could make use of the Microsoft Dreamspark Premium subscription).

Saying that, it's a *Computer Club*, so you really should be doing some other stuff like computer hardware, and other interesting stuff like how videogames work.
Depending completely on how the school feels about it (and also depends on the insurance the school has), you could potentially obtain a grant to order low-grade computer components so that students can build and maintain their own system; if so, I'd advise to use cheap components such as a low-end motherboard & CPU, but with a small 64GB SSD (it's not like they're going to be using all 55GB-or-so of space, are they?).

An alternative to the above is the purchase of older computers (say, 2009-2011 era), you disassemble them completely (and cleaning them out to get rid of all the dust that would likely reside in them), then get the students to rebuild them.

*Yet* another alternative could look at Intel's super-small low-end low-priced NUC computers.

Alternatively you could switch from Python to C++, and there is a pretty neat online 'code 'n compile' site called `Coliru`[(click here to go to it)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), which is completely free *BUT* has no option to save code. One (messy) possibility is to make students save their code on Google Drive or a USB memory stick and retrieve it when they're working on their program(s).

If you ***If you really have to stick to using the Chromebooks, then maybe try asking this question on Stack Overflow instead, as you could potentially get better answers there.***

Comment: My school provides no funding for any clubs, and we only have a couple of members with Chromebooks. And we do not have anyone with experience with C++.

Answer (score 0):

you can use repl.it for python:

- [python 2.7.10](https://repl.it/languages/python)
- [python 3.5.2](https://repl.it/languages/python3)

You code in the left hand side and click "Run".

It's very simple to use and effective.

Comment: Can you expand on why repl.it might be a good thing to use in OP's set of circumstances?

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: OP is asking for an IDE not an online compiler/interpreter.